# How to create a bridge loop without selecting face?

Tags: vertices

[image]

The face in the middle keeps being selected even though i only want to select the vertices of the missing faces to create a bridge between them so that they connect

Comment: May i ask though if the bridging you mention is between the left and right or rather filling in the holes on both sides?
Bridging here would generate 4 faces of which one would be exactly the one you pointed out don't want to select and 1 more in the back that would be overlapping with the one in the back where the "V" shape is formed.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean but I essentially want to fill the gap in the middle of that whole mesh so that you cannot see the other side

Comment: I posted a shorter but visual supported answer which i already had started but gave up on after you accepted the other answer from @Jachym-Michal. Hope that i understood the question right based on the picture.

Comment: I posted another question as I'm stuck again, could you please help me on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting vertices, select the edges.
Just switch to *edge selection* mode, and it will work.

[image]

Comment: You're a life saver, thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help :).

Comment: Okay, I'm stuck again with the same problem. It was working until I only had 3 faces left where the edges are touching each other and so a bridge won't form.

Comment: You can always bridge edges/vertices manually by pressing **F**. If that doesn't work, please edit your question or ask a new one :).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the right question would be how to fill the gaps/holes.

While vertex selection does not work here to do it in one go, each side can be done without a problem, edge selection also works and in some situations avoids the unwanted face selection as well.

I made a video with what i believe you were looking for:

[image: visual explanation]

The Bridge loops tool would create new faces that would overlap 2 faces, the one mentioned in the question and one in the back. Even if you only bridge the top and front, you would close in the face mentioned in the picture, then it would be better to delete the face and bridge from the back to the front, spanning over the 3 edges in the back to the front 3 edges.

Like so:

[image]